# Enable Server Status using Plesk 11

Tags: apache-2.2

I am trying to get apaches server status to work with Plesk 11. But running `sudo /usr/sbin/apache2ctl fullstatus` results in:

```
                                   Forbidden

   You don't have permission to access /server-status on this server.
     __________________________________________________________________


    Apache Server at localhost Port 80
'www-browser -dump http://localhost:80/server-status' failed.
Maybe you need to install a package providing www-browser or you
need to adjust the APACHE_LYNX variable in /etc/apache2/envvars
```

How can I enable server status?

So far I have tried to insert

```
<Location /server-status>
SetHandler server-status

Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from localhost
</Location>
```

into the httpd.conf, but I am not sure if it is active. I also tried adding it to /var/www/vhosts/somedomain/conf/vhost.conf but I do not know which domain I have to add this to, as fullstatus seems to query localhost directly. I guess I am a little confused by the use of vhost configuration in Plesk.

Comment: "I am trying to get apaches server status to work with Plesk 11" : What have you done so far?

Comment: "You don't have permission to access /server-status" : Have you tried accessing server-status by hand (ie use telnet to send http request)

Comment: Has 127.0.0.1/localhost been allowed to access server-status in your apache configuration?

Comment: I updated my question to answer some of your questions!

Comment: The 6 lines are correct, but I guess you have to spot the default virtualhost and add them to it.

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 1):

You most probably have nginx enabled.

That means that apache is not listening in port 80, but in port 7080 (I'm guessing you didn't change the default port).

You can install lynx and access the right port:

```
aptitude install lynx
lynx http://localhost:7080/server-status
```